# Zend Framework Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists in all column

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework

In Zend Framework 1.9.5 is possible to use Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists to validate if a string can't exist in all fields? Something like this:

```
$v=new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(
                                        array(
                                                'table' => 'my_table',
                                                'field' => '*' //to include all columns
                                        ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible the way you have shown. You can't event pass an array of fields as 'field'.

If you really want to use Db_NoRecordExists, you can join multiple instances of it as chain and then add it to your form element:

```
$validatorsChain = new Zend_Validate();

$validator1   = new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(array(
        'table' => 'my_table',
        'field' => 'field1',
));
$validator2   = new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(array(
        'table' => 'my_table',
        'field' => 'field2',
));
$validatorsChain->addValidator($validator1)
                ->addValidator($validator2);

$formElement->addValidator($validatorsChain);
```

like mentioned [here](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/using-multiple-validators-of-the-same-type-on-a-single-field-td658340.html).